# Python for loop - iterating through results

Tags: python

I have this result:

```
(epic:'CC.D.LCO.USS.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 22, 0))
(epic:'IX.D.DAX.DAILY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 23, 4, 0))
(epic:'KB.D.ELECTY.DAILY.IP',timestamp: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 16, 0))
```

I basically want the for loop below to iterate through each of the above row. Note the while loop ends with a `start=row['timestamp']` - This should be the timestamp of the next row's timestamp. However when I run the code at the moment it' just repeats the same URL

```
for row in result:
    #print(row['epic'],row['timestamp'])
    epic=row['epic']
    start=row['timestamp']
    end=datetime.now()
    #print(end)
    fmt = "https://example.api/"+str(epic)+"/1/MINUTE/batch/start/{date1:%Y/%m/%d/%H/00/0/0}/end/{date2:%Y/%m/%d/%H/00/0/0}?format=json"
    while start <= end:
        date1 = start
        date2 = end
        url = fmt.format(date1=date1, date2=date2)
        print(url)
        start = date1
start = row['timestamp']
```

Comment: based on the indentation you have shown `start = row['timestamp']` is not in the `while` loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick, I have tried altering the indentation but still repeats the same value

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Print url's until reach a line with a timestamp later than the current datetime? Anyway, just to give you a hint, in the `while` loop, you are changing neiher the value of `start` (it starts with `date1` and ends with the same) nor the value of `end`, so it will loop forever. Maybe you need there an `if` instead?